# HELP with workflow error: Coercion Failed: Unable to transform the input lookup data into the requested type

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, email, person, workflow-lookup

From reading other posts I know this error is related to null or blank values in the lookup but I don't have that problem.

I have a list of about 10 items in a list called "Service Types" with an "Owner" assigned that is a person field.  ALL 10 have an owner assigned.  In a "Project Request" list, users will select a service type from a drop down (which is a lookup column back to the Service types list so it matches 100%).  When they save I want an email to go to the Owner listed in the Service Type list for the matching item.  For example, Cynthia Thomas is listed as the owner of "Consulting" so if a project comes in with a service type of consulting it should email Cynthia Thomas.

I have already told the workflow to log the value of the Owner's email address to a variable.  And then log that variable to the workflow history list to see it's not blank.  It is working!  So I know that the value is not blank.  The log says the full email of the person in the Owner field for the right item.  Full email like cynthia.thomas@email.com.

The next step is to send an email and I put the variable in the To line.  Again, the variable is cynthia.thomas@email.com format according to the workflow history list log so that SHOULD WORK in the To line.

But the workflow results in the error message "Coercion Failed: Unable to transform the input lookup data into the requested type."  Not sure what I am doing wrong here.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible for you to attach the screenshot of your workflow? Are you using any lookup to field in current item in your email action?

Comment: Also try using LoginName of owner in To field of email action.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  It wasn't a problem with the email address at all.  It was a field in the body of the email that was empty!  Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time this error occurs when you try to access the empty fields from `Current Item`.

Check is there any such actions before email or inside email body which are returning null/empty from list and trying to convert it into another type.